# Condition for convergence of the series $S = \frac{a}{b}+\frac{a(a+1)}{b(b+1)} + \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)}{b(b+1)(b+2)} + \ldots $

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

Let

$$S = \frac{a}{b}+\frac{a(a+1)}{b(b+1)} + \frac{a(a+1)(a+2)}{b(b+1)(b+2)}  + \ldots $$

What is the relationship between $a$ and $b$ for $S$ to be a convergent series ?

---

My attempt:

Letting $u_n$ denote the $nth$ term in the series, we have

$$ u_n = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{i=n-1} (a+i)}{\prod_{j=0}^{j=n-1} (b+j)} $$

We have

$$\frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}} = \frac{(b+n)}{(a+n)}$$

The ratio tests do not lead to progress. Any hints on alternative methods ?

Comment: Use [Raabe's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $u_n$ denote the $nth$ term in the series, we have

$$ u_n = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{i=n-1} (a+i)}{\prod_{j=0}^{j=n-1} (b+j)} $$

Let us try to apply the [ratio test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RatioTest.html).We have

$$lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}} = lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(b+n)}{(a+n)} = 1$$.

This is not very helpful. Let us try another test, called [Raabe's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html). Raabe's test can be tried whenever we have a situation like above where the ratio test gives the limit result as $1$.

Essentially, Raabe's test  finds the following limit

$$lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ n \left( \frac{u_n}{u_{n+1}} - 1 \right) \right] = L$$

If $L > 1$, the series converges. Applying this to our problem, we have

$$lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ n \left( \frac{b+n}{a+n} - 1 \right) \right] = lim_{n \to \infty} \left[ \frac{b-a}{\frac{a}{n}+1} \right] = (b-a)$$

Therefore, the required condition on $a,b$ for the series to be convergent is $ b - a > 1$

(Thanks to Jean-Claude Arbaut for the suggestion)

Answer (score 1):

Multiply and divide your sum by $\dfrac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(b)}$ . You have $S=\dfrac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)}\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{\Gamma(a+n)}{\Gamma(b+n)}=\dfrac{\Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a)}\cdot\dfrac{\Gamma(a+1)}{\Gamma(b)}$ $\cdot\dfrac1{b-a-1}=\dfrac a{b-a-1}$ . Can you take it from here? :-)

Comment: I am not familiar with $\dfrac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(b)}$ . Could you provide a reference ?

Comment: $\Gamma(n+1)=n!$. See [$\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for more details.